# Unknown "array" function.in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I just started to study the symfony 4. In my third app, I am trying to make a simple calendar. I declared an array variable that holds the days but it gives me an error "Unknown "array" function.".

Question: Is there any bundle I need to install to make an array variable in my .html.twig file??

Things that I installed in this app so far:

```
1) composer require symfony/maker-bundle
2) composer require annotations
3) composer require symfony/twig-bundle
```

**My view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }} </title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <th colspan=7>{{ "now"|date("F") ~ " " ~ "now"|date("Y") }} </th>
        </tr>
        {% set x = 1 %}
        {% set day = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday" ) %}
        {{ x ~ day }}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#setting-variables array is not a twig function.

Comment: I tried this {% set foo = {'foo': 'bar'} %} it gives me an error An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array(...)` is PHP, not TWIG.

If you want to create an array in TWIG, use `[...]` instead.

So replace this line

```
    {% set day = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday" ) %}
```

With this one

```
    {% set day = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"] %}
```

**EDIT : How to print the array**

In order to print your array, replace this

```
{{ x ~ day }}
```

With this :

```
{{ day | join(',') }}
```

This line will print everything in your array with a comma between each value. Check [this link](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html) to know more about `join`.

Comment: That's because of the following line : `{{ x ~ day }}`. What are you trying to print ?

Comment: thats right! because `{{ x ~ day }}`. You tring to concatenate 1 with an array.

Comment: You are trying to print an array here, and it's not possible, because TWIG can't cast it to String. What are you trying to print ? Sunday ? Monday ? Everything in the array ?

Comment: Then use `{{ day | join }}` to print everything in your array. Check this link to understand what `join` is : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/join.html

Comment: if you'll use it later why not looping over the array? `{% for  singleDay in [ ... ] %} {{ singleDay }} {% endfor %}
`

Comment: Well, it depends on what @Angel wants to print. Do you want another `<tr>` with seven `<th>`, one for each element of the array ?